# Loop through files in FTP directory using bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp

I have a batch file that is executed by a scheduled windows service every 5 minutes. The batch files executes mget for a specific filemask: *.ext.
After mget it does mdel *.ext.
Recently I encountered a problem: When a file z.ext gets created between the execution of mget and mdel, that file gets deleted but it was not in the mget. Which off course makes sense.
So now I am looking for the proper windows ftp commands that will loop through the files and does a mget and mdel file by file.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

ftp scriptng is very limited, but I think you can use [this approach](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsFtpBatchScript.php#Batch.FtpBatchDownloadOnlyNewFiles). Basically, you have to run the ftp twice, first to collect the list of files to download, then the second time to download (and delete) each file (combined with lots of cmd scripting) You still don't get any error handling and ftp servers are not exactly known for their error tolerance.

The relevant example from the website above is:

```
@Echo Off

REM -- Define File Filter, i.e. files with extension .txt
Set FindStrArgs=/E /C:".txt"

REM -- Extract Ftp Script to create List of Files
Set "FtpCommand=ls"
Call:extractFileSection "[Ftp Script 1]" "-">"%temp%\%~n0.ftp"
Rem Notepad "%temp%\%~n0.ftp"

REM -- Execute Ftp Script, collect File Names
Set "FileList="
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('"Ftp -v -i -s:"%temp%\%~n0.ftp"|Findstr %FindStrArgs%"') Do (
    Call Set "FileList=%%FileList%% "%%A""
)

REM -- Extract Ftp Script to download files that don't exist in local folder
Set "FtpCommand=mget"
For %%A In (%FileList%) Do If Not Exist "%%~A" Call Set "FtpCommand=%%FtpCommand%% "%%~A""
Call:extractFileSection "[Ftp Script 1]" "-">"%temp%\%~n0.ftp"
Rem Notepad "%temp%\%~n0.ftp"

For %%A In (%FtpCommand%) Do Echo.%%A

REM -- Execute Ftp Script, download files
ftp -i -s:"%temp%\%~n0.ftp"
Del "%temp%\%~n0.ftp"
GOTO:EOF


:extractFileSection StartMark EndMark FileName -- extract a section of file that is defined by a start and end mark
::                  -- [IN]     StartMark - start mark, use '...:S' mark to allow variable substitution
::                  -- [IN,OPT] EndMark   - optional end mark, default is first empty line
::                  -- [IN,OPT] FileName  - optional source file, default is THIS file
:$created 20080219 :$changed 20100205 :$categories ReadFile
:$source http://www.dostips.com
SETLOCAL Disabledelayedexpansion
set "bmk=%~1"
set "emk=%~2"
set "src=%~3"
set "bExtr="
set "bSubs="
if "%src%"=="" set src=%~f0&        rem if no source file then assume THIS file
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('find /n /v "" "%src%"') do (
    if /i "%%B"=="%emk%" set "bExtr="&set "bSubs="
    if defined bExtr if defined bSubs (call echo.%%B) ELSE (echo.%%B)
    if /i "%%B"=="%bmk%"   set "bExtr=Y"
    if /i "%%B"=="%bmk%:S" set "bExtr=Y"&set "bSubs=Y"
)
EXIT /b


[Ftp Script 1]:S
!Title Connecting...
open example.com
username
password

!Title Preparing...
cd public_html/MyRemoteDirectory
lcd c:\MyLocalDirectory
binary
hash

!Title Processing... %FtpCommand%
%FtpCommand%

!Title Disconnecting...
disconnect
bye
```

Probably better to just do it in python or some other scripting environment (assuming you don't have deployment issues.)